# How make secondary constructor in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin this is the code I wrote but its showing error at this() of secondary constructor

```
class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, countryModelsList:ArrayList<CountryModel>) :
    ArrayAdapter<CountryModel>(context,R.layout.list_coustom_item,countryModelsList ) {
    constructor() :  this()
```

error is "there is cycle in deligation calls chain"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin constructor (primary constructor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47979047/kotlin-constructor-primary-constructor) (also, your constructor is delegating to itself.)

Comment: yes i got the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by tynn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47979140/2737080),

If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s). Delegation to another constructor of the same class is done using the this keyword:

I am unable to understand exact use case you are trying to solve, but I guess below code will help.

```
class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, resourceId: Int, countryModelsList:ArrayList<CountryModel>) :
ArrayAdapter<CountryModel>(context, resourceId, countryModelsList ) {

constructor(context: Context, countryModelsList: ArrayList<CountryModel>) : this(context, R.layout.list_coustom_item, countryModelsList)

constructor(context: Context): this(context, emptyList<CountryModel>())
```

}